# How to calculate the overlapping values in array?

Tags: probability

Suppose we have array of length N and range of possible values of numbers K. Values of range K may coincide, for example, if N = 5, and K = 1...10 :
[1, 9, 5, 5, 1]. What is a expected quantity of such pairs (5,5 and 1,1) ?
Please, it is possible more in detail, for dummies.

Comment: I think you need to clarify a few points. Presumably the numbers in the array are uniformly randomly distributed. By pairs, do you mean two numbers in a row? In addition, for $n$ identical numbers in a row, this would count as $n-1$ pairs?

Comment: If so, then use linearity of expectation and count the 'pairs' by only considering the chances that a number forms a 'pair' with the one behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by 'for dummies' you mean without using only math, you can consider that the array of numbers is generated this way. I will first go with a particular case, then generalize it. Say you have a normal die, that is, it has $6$ faces, and each face has a number on it $(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)$. You throw the die and remember the value that you got on each throw. By direct comparison with your scenario, the values $(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)$ represent the range of possible values of numbers $K$, and the number of times you throw the die is $N$, so the values that make your array are the values you got on the die. Also, in this particular case, the probability of getting one particular number out of the range of possible values is $1/6$.

What your question now translates to is 'what is the probability of getting the value $x$ in $n$ throws out of a total of $N$'. If we particularize $x=1$ and we want to have this result $n=4$ times out of $N=10$ throws, then you can group your result in two categories:

- success, when the result is $1$, and it has $1/6$ probability of taking place for one throw of the die
- failure, when the result is not $1$, which corresponds to all the other $5$ scenarios, so this has the probability of $5/6$

Based on this formulation of the problem, you can use the [Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) to get your answer for this particular case.

Once you understand the way the Binomial Distribution works, you should be able to consider a more general scenario such as taking a die with more than $6$ values, or with probabilities that are not equal for each face.

Now, to give you a hint on what the general case looks like, the way I see it. Let $K$ be the set of all possible values, with elements $k_i \in K$ such that $k_i=k_j$ iff $i=j$. Consider $P(k_i)$ the probability of selecting the value $k_i$ of the $K$. The elements of the array will be generated based on the probability function $P(k_i)$. I will consider that the length of the array is $N$ as you did, and that I want to find the probability of having the value $k_i$ for $n$ out of $N$ numbers in it.

Again using the Binomial Distribution, the success has the probability $P(k_i)$, the failure has the probability $1-P(k_i)$ so using the formula from the link I used above, should give you the probability of $n$ successes out of $N$, for the value $k_i$. Repeat the process for all values in $K$ and you should have your answer.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Excelent, thanks